# Parallax in the FOOTER only

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, parallax

I created a parallax footer for my new project: [Parallax Footer](https://codepen.io/ch4ppy/pen/KRXPNG), but as soon as I add a div above it to simulate the actual homepage: [Parallax Footer w/ Simulated Content](https://codepen.io/ch4ppy/pen/QrqLdV), it ceases to function and I feel like I understand why, but I can't seem to figure out how to correct it. It's like I have to trigger the parallax at a certain point but I have no idea how to do it. Any nudges in the right direction would be super helpful.

this is my js, which I borrowed from another pen:

```
  var opThresh = 350;
  var opFactor = 750;

  window.addEventListener("scroll", function (event) {

     var top = this.pageYOffset;

     var layers = document.getElementsByClassName("parallax");
     var layer, speed, yPos;
     for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
        layer = layers[i];
        speed = layer.getAttribute('data-speed');
        var yPos = -(top * speed / 100);
        layer.setAttribute('style', 'transform: translate3d(0px, ' + yPos + 'px, 0px)');

     }
  });
}
document.body.onload = castParallax();
```

Comment: But main question is: what do You want to achieve with the div? Should the content of the div stay over the #parallax? or should it push it down? This is exactly what happens it Your example. DIV's height is 1000px and it pushes #parallax content down so it is not visible anymore, but it is there.

Comment: @zolv the idea is that it will act as a footer and the parallax will work once the user reaches the footer but the rest of the homepage content will act normally. So the 1000px div is to simulate the rest of the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

How about to set #parallax positioned absolute:

```
#parallax {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: This just puts the footer on top of the rest of the content. I see where your head is at, but it does not achieve the result I am after. I am hoping to have the footer act exactly like it does in my first pen, just at the bottom of my homepage.